# React Dynamically render component within div based on div id

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-chartjs, react-vis

I am building a discrete bar graph component from scratch to display flights arrival/departure for every hour of the day. I need to basically match some of the data (flight and time) to a particular div and render it within the div. For example [in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPXvK.png), I need to get the list of airplanes, determine whether it is for Arrivals/destinations and match it to the x-axis time range and render it within the appropriate div. I can have unique div ids see example

```
{
    "AirplaneData": {
      "Arrivals":[
        {"BIO": "0:00"}, 
        {"VGU": "2.00"}, 
        {"MEX": "4.00"}],
      "Departures": [
        {"BIO": "3:00"}, 
        {"VGU": "4.00"}, 
        {"MEX": "6.00"}]
      
    }
  }
```

```
  <div className={classes.bars}>
    <div className={classes.graph}>
      <div className={classes.bar} key="somekey">{DISPLAY SOME COMPONENT HERE}</div>
      <div className={classes.label1}><span style= {{marginLeft: "10px"}}>0.00</span></div>
      <div className={classes.bar}></div>
    </div>
    <div className={classes.graph}>
      <div className={classes.bar} key="someotherkey"><h1>{DISPLAY SOME COMPONENT HERE}</h1></div>
      <div className={classes.label2}><span style= {{marginLeft: "10px"}}>1.00</span></div>
      <div className={classes.bar}></div>
    </div>
</div>

.... repeat divs for every hour
```

How do I render the airplane time data within the appropriate divs (basically matching the div key to the time from the airplane data.)

Comment: id recommend a different approach...take the flight data objects...transform it a list of objects that match the GUI design...then from there it's a simple map of the new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're saying you want to render content dynamically from a list of data? I would look into the `map` and `filter` functions.

With your example, you could return a set of divs using your array of data. similar to this concept `airplaneDataArray.map(data => return <div>...</div>);`

The "data" within the mapped array pretty much represents a single piece in the array, so you'd be able to call specific parts of the array using `data.arrivals.key`, and so on and so forth. This will generate the divs dynamically without hardcoding a bunch of div rows.

Now if you only want to get arrivals at a specific time, you could use filter to filter out arrivals that don't match the time you want. Honestly not exactly understanding your use case that much so a better example, or something more indepth would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I think this kinda makes sense. I am not super happy with hardcoding a bunch of divs either. For my use-case I dont really need to filter out arrivals or departures. All I need is a way to take thats airplane data and display it visually . I might need to sort the flights for a certain time visually (but that can be done easily). The only part I am wondering about is the need to make sure that if there are no arrivals/departures for a given time ex: in the diagram 0:00 has no flights it displays just the background.

Comment: Okay, if you're displaying by time, my suggestion is you should have a different data structure. Instead, your time should be a top level key and then each flight for the time should be nested under that. Like under arrivals have "00:00": { "BIO": "00:00" }, or even better, just store each flight in an array "00:00": ["BIO", "VLG", etc.]. Then you can iterate through the keys of data and display the key, and then easily display flights.

Comment: Thank you ! this is what i am thinking! Appreciate the help!